# Speeding up code - 3D array

Tags: java

I'm trying to improve the speed of some code I've written. I was wondering how efficient accessing data from a 3d array of integers is?

I have an array

`int cube[][][] = new int[10][10][10];`

which I populate with values. I then access these values several thousand times.

I was wondering, seeing as all 3d arrays are theoretically stored in 1D arrays in memory, is there a way to turn my 3d array into a 1d one? For instance I could have cube[0] referring to the old cube[0][0][0] and cube [1] refering to the old cube[0][0][1].

I'm not sure how to go about doing it. I'm sure it's possible but my brain is worn out.

Thanks

Comment: Do you have any evidence that it's slow?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create the single-dimension array as follows:

```
int cube[] = new int[w * h * d];
```

And to access an element:

```
int value = cube[x * h * d + y * d + z];
```

But I doubt it will be much faster and you're losing some convenience and safety. Before deciding to go through with this change it might be a good idea to perform some benchmark tests on your data to see if you actually have a problem and whether the change gives a sufficiently large improvement to be worth the extra complexity.

Comment: I have tried micro-benchmarking this.  For a trivial loop assigning random numbers to random locations in the array 10,000,000 times, the single-dimension version actually *is* marginally faster on my computer (3.6 seconds rather than 4.6 seconds).  I doubt it would be worth bothering with in the context of a program that is only accessing the data "a few thousand times".

Comment: ...and don't forget cache hits/misses based on usage pattens and size... what a fickle thing a CPU is.

Comment: I agree with your suggestion but I think it *will* be faster. My reasoning is: all multi-dimensional arrays in Java are jagged so getting an element involves pointer dereferencing rather than just multiplication. It can't use multiplication, think about what will happen after executing this statement: `cube[2][3] = new int[42];`. How will the JVM use multiplication to work out the correct memory address when all the arrays can have different sizes?

Comment: @Ramon: Good point! I've modified the warning at the end of my answer.

Answer (score 1):

That's exactly what Java is doing behind the scenes. A three dimensional array is simply an array of arrays of arrays. In theory you could separate the arrays into 10 two dimensional arrays or 100 one-dimensional arrays (and even into 1000 individual variables), but it would be unlikely to speed up your performance. Focus on optimizing your algorithm instead.

Comment: It's (the question is about) the *opposite* of what Java does then -- there is no Nd->1d mapping.

Comment: Oops. I misread the question. I think my answer still applies, though. Regardless of how you transform the data (short of using getters and setters for everything which would kill the performance), the OP isn't going to get much benefit.

Answer (score 1):

```
int cube[] = new int[ X*Y*Z ];
cube[ i*X*Y + j*X + k ] = ...
```

But, as others already said: It's not expected to be faster (as the calculations have to be done anyway). Let Java do its stuff for reasons of error-avoidance.

Answer (score 0):

Do not do it - Java handles all this for you. You can of course make it a 1D array and then do the calculations but you will hardly beat the optimized JVM code which does the same on the background. Also - is this really causing a performance bottleneck according to a profiler? If not, you might optimize your code prematurely.

Comment: As noted in my comment to Mark Byers' answer, using the 1D array *can* actually beat the "optimized JVM code" in a microbenchmark.  You're right that it's not likely to improve performance in practice, though.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a LinkedList and store a 2D array in each Node.  That would be more efficient I believe.

Comment: Indexed lookups in LinkedLists are O(n). That'd could be terrible for a 3d array!