# Java 3D array: Storing cube, retrieving slice of cube

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, slice

When working with an odd, cubic 3d array (3x3x3, 5x5x5, 7x7x7, etc), what would be the most efficient way to return a 2d slice of that array, given the axis on which to orient the slice and a value to use to determine the slice's relevant position along that axis?

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you mean by "axis" and "slice"? Are the axises aligned with the x-y-z directions? If they're not, what do you want returned in the case where your cross section isn't rectangular?

Comment: Yeah, the axis would be, say, an int 0/1/2 that would correspond to the x/y/z axis that are centered in the middle of the original array, then the value could be an offset from the center 0/+1/-1/etc, or from the side. A slice in this case would be a 2d array oriented perpendicular to the specified axis and offset by the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have a three-option choice to make, depending on what you want your input and output of the slicing method to be:

- Slicing works on a primitive multi-dimensional Java array, produces a primitive multi-dimensional Java array, e.g.:

`int[][] ArrayUtils.slice(int[][][] cube, int axis, int sliceIndex)`

- Slicing works on a primitive multi-dimensional Java array, produces an object with getters e.g.:

`SomeKindOf2DimArrayClass ArrayUtils.slice(int[][][] cube, int axis, int sliceIndex)`

- Slicing uses non-primitive arrays both as input and output, and is a method of such a class:

`SomeKindOf2DimArrayClass slice(int axis, int sliceIndex)`

That's as far as your interface is concerned.

Implementation-wise, if you're using primitive arrays then you don't have much choice but to do some 'heavy lifting' - build a 2d array for the siice - at least for the 3rd axis. For the first axis you'll just take one of the 2d arrays (i.e. `result = Arrays.copyOf(cube[sliceIndex])`, or even just use the reference if you're feeling frisky); for the second axis you'll have something like

```
for(int i=0; i<cube.length; i++) {
    myAllocated2dArray[i] = Arrays.copyOf(cube[i][sliceindex])
}
```

If you're using an object, you have lots of options, from what I've just described to what @Aquillo suggested in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15997301/1593077) here, to O(1)-space wrappers for the original arrays with getter methods.

You might get some inspiration regarding the two implementations already suggested by reading an answer regarding a similar question in the [C language FAQs](http://c-faq.com/index.html), where the use of pointers (references) is explicit:

> [How can I use statically- and dynamically-allocated multidimensional arrays interchangeably when passing them to functions?](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/ary2dfunc3.html)

Answer (score 1):

Since this is a quite interesting subject to me, I have been searching for an answer too. I think you might be in luck with the approach by [Mark Byers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4179745/speeding-up-code-3d-array):

Instead of storing this in a 3D array, Mark has a very nice approach in how to use a 1D array.

After some trying I've come up with the complete cube, hope this suites you:

```
public class Cube {
    int w, h, d;
    int[] cube;

    public Cube(int w, int h, int d) {
        this.w = w;
        this.h = h;
        this.d = d;
        System.out.println("cube: w" + w + ", h" + h + ", d" + d + " = " + (w * h * d));
        cube = new int[w * h * d];
    }

    int getCubeValue(int x, int y, int z) {
        return cube[x * h * d + y * d + z];
    }

    void setCubeValue(int x, int y, int z, int value) {
        System.out.println("value " + (x * h * d + y * d + z) + ": x" + x + ", y" + y + ", z" + z + " = " + value);
        cube[x * h * d + y * d + z] = value;
    }

    int[] xSlice(int x) {
        int[] slice = new int[h * d];
        for(int y = 0; y < h; y++) {
                for(int z = 0; z < d; z++) {
                        slice[y * d + z] = getCubeValue(x, y, z);
                }
        }
        return slice;
    }

    int xSliceValue(int[] slice, int y, int z) {
        return slice[y * d + z];
    }

    int[] ySlice(int y) {
        int[] slice = new int[d * w];
        for(int z = 0; z < d; z++) {
                for(int x = 0; x < w; x++) {
                        slice[z * w + x] = getCubeValue(x, y, z);
                }
        }
        return slice;
    }

    int ySliceValue(int[] slice, int x, int z) {
        return slice[z * w + x];
    }

    int[] zSlice(int z) {
        int[] slice = new int[w * h];
        for(int x = 0; x < w; x++) {
            for(int y = 0; y < h; y++) {
                slice[x * h + y] = getCubeValue(x, y, z);
            }
        }
        return slice;
    }

    int zSliceValue(int[] slice, int x, int y) {
        return slice[x * h + y];
    }
}
```

Say you make a Cube like this `new Cube(3, 3, 3)`, the last value will be approachable by `cube.getCubeValue(2, 2, 2)` since it starts on zero.